# Does an Azure WebApp require Roslyn CodeAnalysis Dlls?

Tags: azure, web-applications, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've developed my test webapp in VS2017 and am now using Web Publish to push the code to Azure.

1. Are the bin\Roslyn dlls required?
2. Including the 5MB Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll !?
3. How to exclude them from the publish process?

Comment: also posted in https://serverfault.com/questions/932896/do-azure-webapps-require-the-bin-roslyn-folder